# Or statements for complex regex formation in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to formulate a regex to pick up only the first part of a particular string rather than the second part. For example:

```
      (part1)                        (Part2)    
        SAI                           Table


                                      Cloth


       DARA
```

I want to extract only `SAI` (i.e. part1 and not part2). Notice that the 2nd line is empty in part 1 and hence it should return an empty space (and not `cloth`). The same regex must work for all three cases of strings. In the case of string2 part one must return a blank space and not `table`. There is no certain length of spaces between the two parts. It varies.

This is the regex I tried, but it only works for string1 and string3:

```
[\s]{1,}((?:[a-zA-Z)(@\-,."'',&*]+[\s]?)+)[\s]{2,}
```

Is there any way to write a regex that would work in this case?

I can only use regex here as I need it to return any string present there. The string can be alpha-numerals and may contain the most popularly used symbols present in my earlier regex. The space between the two is never fixed.

I also need it to return a space where it is empty in part 1. We can ignore part 2. But I have to make sure that the regex does not match part 2.

Comment: You should provide some more info: what are the properties of the part that you wish to match? only capital letters? certain length? Do you even need regex, or can you simply use `split` on the whitespace chars?

Comment: Are there any separators betwen part1 and part2? i.e. spaces, tab,...

Comment: That is the problem. There is no certain length of spaces between the two parts. It varies. Can only use regex here as I need it to return any string present there. The string can be alpha-numerals and may contain the most popularly used symbols present in my earlier regex. The space between the two is never fixed. And I need it to return a space where it is empty in part 1. We can ignore part 2. But need to make sure that the regex doesnt recognize part 2 as part1 when part1 is empty like in case2.

Comment: Doesn't work because in case3 DARA is coming under part 2 of the match whereas I need it to come under part 1. This is the code I'm using. 
 m = re.search(regex,strn)
 if len(m.group(1))!=0 :
  z['y']=z['x']+' ' + m.group(1).strip()

 Using an re.M flag doesn't work because the line doesn't end with a character but with an empty space most of the time.

Comment: I can't think of a pattern that will work in 100% cases, perhaps, you can rely on a specific number of spaces that cannot be more than you specify before the first group: [`^\d+\.[ \t]{1,10}(\S*)(?:[ \t]+(\S+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/cJ0oB9/1). Best is to remove the bullet number and split the string at some point. Or a regex won't help at all.

Comment: You can ignore the bullet nos. I'll get those out.

Comment: So, is [the approach](https://regex101.com/r/cJ0oB9/2) working?

Comment: Is *part1* **always** followed by 2 spaces, and *part2* **never** followed by 2 spaces? I'd use that condition

Comment: According to my answer, you may go with this as well [`(?: +((?:\w+)?))?(?: +((?:\w+)?))`](https://regex101.com/r/uB7wV6/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first column (*part1*) is **always** followed by 2 spaces, whereas the second (*part2*) is not, you can rely on that condition to prevent a match in the last column. We can use the [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=[\t ]{2})` to assert for 2 consecutive spaces or tabs.

**Code**

```python
import re

patt = r'^[\t ]*(\S+(?:[\t ]\S+)*(?=[\t ]{2})| )'
str = r'''
      (part1)                        (Part2)    
        SAI                           Table
                                      Cloth
       DARA                                 
'''

print re.findall(patt, str, re.MULTILINE)
```

**Output**

```
['(part1)', 'SAI', ' ', 'DARA']
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/lqvLXX)</kbd>

You may as well change `\S` to `[a-zA-Z)(@\-,."'',&*]` to limit the allowed characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using named capturing groups you are able to distinguish between captured parts:

```
(?: +(?P<one>(?:\w+)?))?(?: +(?P<two>(?:\w+)?))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uB7wV6/2)